# How much is a Berry in One Piece worth?

Tags: money, one-piece

In One Piece the major currency appears to be the Berry. Bounties for various pirates seem to clock in at around the 10 to 20 million range.

When Nami is looking at ducking out from the Straw hat crew a life to the nearest shore is quoted as 6,000 berry.

In episode 9 we see Arlong has promised to sell Coco village to Nami for 100 million berry. Which in the context of the episode is made out to be huge.

In that same episode though we see the survival fee when Arlong takes Coco village appears to be 100,000 berry and Nami's mum just happens to have that sitting in a box despite appearing to live in abject poverty without the ability to buy fresh biscuits.

How much is a Berry? Happy to have a real world currency value or even an understandably small purchase as a scale, glass of whiskey, ordinary meal etc.

Comment: According to the wiki, [that's her life savings](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Belly)

Comment: Right, that was the impression that I got too. She couldn't buy biscuits or otherwise afford anything of value because she had to save all the money she had for Arlong's frankly ludicrous taxes, which were never designed to be affordable, more to give him some income until he got around to killing everyone in the village, or give him an excuse to kill people in the meantime. I doubt he ever even expected most people in the village to come up with their share.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A Berry (or [Belly](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Belly)) appears to hew closely to how the Japanese Yen works.

There are never any prices expressed in anything less than a whole Berry, just like the Yen. It also appears that 100 or so Berries isn't a lot of money. For instance [this site about Yen prices](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/en/life/livingcost-price/) (based on 2022 surveys) pegs 1kg (about 2.2lb) of bread at 479 yen. There isn't a price for bread in One Piece, but the Belly page linked above lists a single cabbage at 150 Berries. The 2022 Yen price survey puts it about 146 Yen. I would say a 1 to 1 ratio for the purposes of comparison isn't unfair.

As of this writing, one US Dollar is about 149 Yen (it's been as low as 128 yen in Jan 2023).

Comment: By the way: The wiki article linked in this answer has a lot more examples of product prices that give an idea of the value of a Berry/Belly.

Comment: @Philipp Yeah, but not a lot of apples-to-apples comparisons. A t0shirt being expensive at 10K berries was harder to cross-reference.

Comment: I have to admit, saying ~135k Dollars is a lot less imposing than 20M Berry

Comment: @JohnDoe It's true, but it's a function of not having any sub-currency. Functionally, 1 Yen is like $0.01, so everything is off by a factor of 100. A used car, on average, costs 1.6M Yen, compared to $16,000.